# Excel VBA: how to find the first row number of the Page1

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to find out the first row number of the page1.

Using the following code can find the last row number of page 1.

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").HPageBreaks(1).Location.Row - 1
```

But I have to find the first row number of Page1.

Would anyone has idea on it?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Well, the first row number is usually 1 ;) But as I guess you mean the first non-empty row I would suggest just looping through the rows of e.g. column A until you find a non-empty cell. Won't be that time consuming (unless your sheet starts somewhere around row 1000).

Comment: On my phone only, does `.Location.Address` shows you the range?

Comment: hi sina, in my excel application, the first row number of page 1 is varying. Sometimes it is 1, but sometimes it is 100. (with row 1 ~99 are hidden) How to determine it? thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could try with `Sheets().PageSetup.PrintArea` property. This will return the address of range for all your pages. As a result you get something like this:

```
$G$12:$P$31   << for continuous range/pages >> see 1st screen shot below
$G$12:$P$31;$B$5:$E$20;$R$5:$U$20   << for non-continuous ranges/pages >> see 2nd screen shot below
```

**1st Picture:**
[image]

**2nd Picture:**
[image]

Each time above the first row number is the first row number on first page. To get it you could try with one of the following solutions:

```
firstRow = Range(Replace(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").PageSetup.PrintArea, ";", ",")).Row
```

or with the following solution:

```
firstRow = Split(Split(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").PageSetup.PrintArea, ":")(0),"$")(2)
```

**Additional explanation**

Range address which you get from `.PrintArea property` uses semi-colon `(;)` to separate non-continuous ranges. We need to convert it to comma `(,)` if we want to use it in first solution above.

Answer (score 1):

You can use SpecialCells to get the first visible row.

The below code will return back the address for the first visible row of the ActiveSheet

```
msgbox ActiveSheet.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Rows(1).Address
```

or if you just want the row number

```
msgbox ActiveSheet.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Rows(1).Row
```

Answer (score 0):

This will get you the first row of the first page:

```
Sub dural()
    Dim nRow As Long, s As String
    Dim r As Range
    s = Sheets("Sheet1").PageSetup.PrintArea
    Set r = Range(s)
    nRow = r(1).Row
    MsgBox nRow
End Sub
```

Comment: there is a trick in your solution. If you have pages which are not continuous range you will get their address separated with semi-colon (;) which is not acceptable to separate address ranges in `Range(s)`. Therefore you need to replace it with comma (,) as I did in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The following is not the nicest way of coding I have to admit. But I think, it is easy to read and it does the job (if I understood the problem correct).

```
Sub runningThroughSheets()

  Dim wsht As Worksheet
  Dim wholeRow As Range
  Dim counter As Integer
  Dim stopSearch As Boolean

  Set wsht = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

  counter = 0
  stopSearch = False
  Do While stopSearch = False
    If Range("A1").Offset(counter, 0).EntireRow.Hidden = False Then
        stopSearch = True
    End If
    counter = counter + 1
  Loop

  MsgBox counter

End Sub
```